# How to train a LSTM for multiple series instances?

Tags: python, deep-learning, lstm

I've to train an LSTM to predict some time series. I've read [this](http://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-prediction-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/) tutorial about LSTM using Tensorflow and Keras and I think that it could be a solution for my problem.
In my task I have an input feature X (extracted from an image), and the corresponding output series y (associated to that image).
My aim is to give the LSTM X and a few of the first y values (say the first n of the series) and predict the further values of y.

In the tutorial the LSTM has to learn a unique time series, but in my case I have a time series for each image, which depends on the feature X (and the previous values of y).

A model suitable for my problem is the one in the figure 1 of [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.01121v3.pdf) paper. In which the input of the LSTM is the feature extracted from the image (constant), and a few first values of the sequence to predict . In this paper, the sequence is the concatenation of a question and an answer, the model learns the concatenation of question and answer so that it predicts the answer after it ends to read the question.

Another example is the one in [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.00468v6.pdf) paper, however I don't understand how I should format the input of the different images to learn the associated sequences.
NB: in my case, each sequence is a series of real values

How should be formatted the input?

Comment: Have you looked at using attention? It can be combined with convolutions, e.g. conv seq2sec: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.03122.pdf